# Rails acts_as_taggable_on grouped alphabetically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable

Having sorted the tag_counts hash via the following code:

sorted_tags = Contact.tag_counts.sort{ |x,y| x.name.downcase <=> y.name.downcase }

what is the easiest/most efficient way to display the tags in my view grouped by letters?

i.e

A - "Alpha", "Apple", "Aza"

B - "Beta", "Bonkers"

.

.

.

Z - "Zeta", "Zimmer"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a way, not sure if its the most efficient or most elegant but here goes:

```
-sorted_tags = Contact.tag_counts.sort{ |x,y| x.name.upcase <=> y.name.upcase }.map(&:name)

%ul

  -"A".upto("Z") do |l|

    %li="#{l} = #{ sorted_tags.select{ |x| x.upcase.starts_with?(l)}.map{|k| link_to k, k}.join(" ") }"
```